# Защищён ли метод store в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

изучаю laravel и вот возник вопрос
нужно ли проверять типы файлов при загрузке и методе сохранения store()?
как я понимаю он просто сохраняет файл без каких либо проверок на его расширение/тип файла
или может быть есть какой либо метод для загрузки защищённый? чтобы обезопасить проект.
заранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Валидацию Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#basic-usage-of-mime-rule

```
'image' => 'required|image'
```

или

```
'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg'
```

Создается класс для Request валидации

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg'
        ];
    }
}
```

Метод store принимает аргумент. В случае если валидация не пройдет, будет ошибка.

```
public function store(FileRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $file = File::create($input);
      
        return back()->with('success', 'File created successfully.');
    }
```

Comment: проверка по mime-типу дырявая. надо либо проверять расширение либо насильно давать расширение по  миме типу